# A038125 Sequence Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine if there is a way to predict if the $n$th term of the following sequence (A038125, $\sum_{k=0}^n (k-n)^k$) will be positive or negative:

$$0^0$$

$$1^0 - 0^1$$

$$2^0 - 1^1 + 0^2$$

$$3^0 - 2^1 + 1^2 - 0^3$$

There seems to be roughly equal amounts of positive and negative values (I've taken it out several thousand terms), but I'm not able to predict the occurrence of negative and positive values.  Also, a negative or positive value never appears more than two times consecutively in the range I've calculated; I would like to prove that the run length of the parity can never exceed two.  There seems like there should be a straightforward solution to these problems, but I still don't see a viable path forward.